# Function to return middle letter or letters of a palindrome

Tags: c#

I'm writing a function to test if a string is a palindrome or not and I am wondering how to return the middle letter or letters if the string is indeed a palindrome?

Here's what i have so far:

My bool to check if the string is a palindrome:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string input)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = input.Length - 1;
    while (true)
    {
        if (i > j)
        {
            return true;
        }
        char a = input[i];
        char b = input[j];

        if (!a.Equals(b))
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

And here is where I'd like to be able to print out the middle letter(s):

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Regex myRegex = new Regex("[ ;:,.-?'!\"]");
    string userInput = String.Empty;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter sentence or phrase");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();

    if (IsPalindrome(myRegex.Replace(userInput, string.Empty).ToLower()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static string GetMiddleLetters(string input)
{
    //Find the middle point
    var mid = input.Length / 2.0;

    //If it's odd, we take 1 letter, if it's even, we take 2
    var numToTake = (mid == (int)mid) ? 2 : 1;

    //Round up from the middle, and subtract one (as Substring is 0-indexed)
    var startIndex = (int)Math.Ceiling(mid) - 1;

    return input.Substring((int)Math.Ceiling(mid) - 1, numToTake);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var fixedString = myRegex.Replace(userInput, string.Empty).ToLower();
if (IsPalindrome(fixedString))
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetMiddleLetters(fixedString));
    //Rest of the code here...
}
```

Comment: Answer provided best fist in with my original code. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's another implementation to return the middle letter(s):

```
public string MiddleLettersOf(string s)
{
    if (s.Length == 0)
        return "";

    if ((s.Length & 1) == 1) // Odd length?
        return s.Substring(s.Length/2, 1);

    return s.Substring(s.Length/2-1, 2);
}
```

(This assumes that passing a null string is an error and therefore I allow it to throw a NullReferenceException.)

By the way, a simple (but not the most efficient) way of checking a string to see if it's a palindrome is:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    return s.SequenceEqual(s.Reverse());
}
```

You can generalise that test to any IEnumerable:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome<T>(IEnumerable<T> s)
{
    return s.SequenceEqual(s.Reverse());
}
```

but the flaw with that code is that `s` is enumerated twice, which might be A Bad Thing.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
public static String MiddleLetters(string value) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value; // middle of the "null" is supposed to be null 

  return value.Length % 2 == 0 ? 
     value.Substring(value.Length / 2 - 1, 2) 
   : value.Substring(value.Length / 2, 1);
}
```

To test for being *palindrome*:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string value) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return true; // or false, or throw an exception  

  //TODO: are you looking for case sensitive or case insensitive palindromes?
  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length / 2; ++i)
    if (value[i] != value[value.Length - i - 1])
      return false;

   return true;
}
```